# How do I approach this problem (Cubes within a larger cube)??

Tags: geometry

**Problem statement**: A cube of $8cm\times 8cm \times8cm$ is divided into smaller cubes of $1cm \times 1cm \times 1cm$ and all the smaller cubes are numbered and arranged to form the larger cube. The smaller cubes are numbered such that the number on the cube represents the smallest volume enclosed by extending the sides of the cube to the outer surface of the largest cube and each cube bears the same number on each surface.

1)Find the sum of the numbers on the cubes along the two body diagonals of the largest cube.

2) Find the number of cubes bearing the numbers which are multiple of three. 
3) Find the sum of numbers on all the smaller cubes on the surface of the larger cube.
4) Find the number of cubes bearing the number $8$ on them.

I went through the given solutions but I hardly understood anything.
Here are all the four solutions.
Solution 1[image]

Solution 2[image]

Solution 3[image]

Solution 4
[image: Solution 4]

I'm not able to picture what's given in the problem.
I need some help.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is badly worded. "Sides" for example is rarely applied to a cube, preferring "faces." I can't figure out the numbering from the description at all.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Do the solutions make any sense to you?

Comment: From the answers, it seems to mean that you are trying to find the smallest volume you can get by cutting out a "corner" of the cube which includes the smaller cube.

Comment: Here is what I think : All the surface cubes of 8x8x8 cube bear number 1 and when you peel off all the surfaces then you will find number 8 on all the surface cubes of the resulting cube(6x6x6)and so on.

Comment: That's certainly not how the answers indicate the numbering works, @mac07, so it is not the intent, although, as I've said, the question is unclear. The answers indicate that the small cube at position $(i,j,k)$ would be numbered $\min(i,9-i)\cdot\min(j,9-j)\cdot\min(k,9-k)$, where $1\leq i,j,k\leq 8$.

Comment: So, consider the large cube as a cake, and you are only allowed to make three cuts to the cake, one from each direction (up/down, left-right, front-back) such that you are cutting along the plane of the smaller cube's face. What is the smallest "piece" of cake you can get this way that contains your smaller cube?

Comment: I can make maximum 8 such three cuts right? In that case, I would get 1x1x1 cube as the smallest. is it right?

Answer (score 1):

The question is very badly worded, but from the answers, I think it is meant to be taken this way.

> Treat the $8\times 8\times 8$ cube as a cake.
>
> Given one of the smaller cubes, we cut the cake along three planes in three different directions, so that the planes are extensions of the faces of the smaller cube.
>
> The smaller cube is labeled with the smallest piece of cake obtained by such cuts which contains the smaller cube.

If you label the smaller cubes as triples $(i,j,k)$ with $1\leq i,j,k\leq 8$, then the cube would be labeled:

$$v(i,j,k)=\min(i,9-i)\min(j,9-j)\min(k,9-k)$$

That's because your cut piece will have either $i$ or $9-i$ for the edge length, depending on which side of it you cut, and same for $j,k$.

Now (1) amounts to wanting:

$$v(1,1,1)+v(2,2,2)+\cdots+v(8,8,8)=1^2+2^3+3^3+4^3+4^3+3^3+2^2+1^3$$

as the answer above states.

For (2), you want at least one of $\min(i,9-i),\min(j,9-j),\min(k,9-k)$. This means tat either $i=3,6$ or $j=3,6$, or $k=3,6$.

It's easier to count the ones that are not of this form - that is, where $i,j,k\in\{1,2,4,5,7,8\}$ then there are $6^3=216$ such triples, and thus $8^3-6^3=296$.

For (3), again, the phrasing is odd. What the answer seems to compute is the sum of the values on the faces of the cubes on the surface, not the sum of the values on the cubes on the surface. So, the corners for example have three faces on the surface, and thus are counted three times.

The formula for $v$ lets us see that we need to factor $8$ into three values no bigger than $4$, which means $8=4\cdot 2\cdot 1$ or $8=2\cdot2\cdot 2.$ You'll have to count these cases up sepearately.

Comment: In 3rd line, Given one of the "smaller cubes"  means 1x1x1 cubes?

Comment: For (2), why are you doing 6^3 to count the ones that are not multiple of 3?

Comment: I'm still finding it difficult to create that image in mind.

Comment: Because it is easier than counting the ones that are multiples of $3$? @mac07

Comment: No . I mean how 6^3 gives the exact count for the ones that are not multiple of 3?

Comment: I think I got it. It's 6^3 because there are three places and 6 numbers and each of these places has six options ,so 6^3 . Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Can you please explain why you are doing this v(i,j,k)=min(i,9−i)min(j,9−j)min(k,9−k)?